# use :content pseudo-element to change non-first <thead> <th> element content

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm still learning more about CSS every day and continue to be surprised by what is possible.  For example I just learned about the first-child pseudo element - had NO idea you could do that!  So, because I continue to be surprised I thought I would ask here if there is a way to accomplish what I'm after, even though I'm not able to find a solution.

I want to change the content in  elements in a  of a table that is displayed on non-first pages.  In other words, when a table breaks onto a new page and the  is rendered again I would like to append content ("Cont...") to the header cells.

I banged out a really simple example that when you Print Preview in your browser will produce two pages, each with two rows.  On the SECOND page I'd like to use CSS to change the content of the  elements.

Anyone have any ideas?  I MUST do this with CSS, I can't change the main html, I can only change the styles.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Column 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Column 2
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
                <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="page-break-after:always;">
                <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
                <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3, Column 1</td>
                <td>Row 3, Column 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 4, Column 1</td>
                <td>Row 4, Column 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `:first-child` is a pseudo-class and `content` is a property, not a selector.

Comment: @BoltClock - right, typo, title should have read use :content AND pseudo-element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the :nth-child pseudo-element.

http://css-tricks.com/5452-how-nth-child-works/

You can target only specific rows with :nth-child(), or :nth-of-type(). I'm not certain that :nth-child can handle a range though, so you may have to chain you css rather annoyingly like:

```
:nth-child(3), :nth-child(4), :nth-child(eleventy!!1!) {properties}
```

More:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html

Now, of course - if you were using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) - this chaining would be simple. Check both items out.

Comment: @adc - I was hopeful, but it didn't work.  While testing I just tried
thead:first-child tr
{
    color:red;
}

to see if that would even treat each page's thead > tr individually but it doesn't.

Looks like I may be SOL on this one.  Thanks for the info, didn't know about nth-child()!

Comment: Sure thing @steve-k. Sorry that this didn't work for ya. It sounds like you have no access to the HTML? Can you use js? If so - you could inject classes onto things via JS.

Comment: @adc - it's actually special html that is then fed to a PDF generation library.  I do have access to the source markup, but I can't change it at runtime.  No javascript.  Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Ha! What a coincidence. I had to write some stylesheets for a PDF generation tool also. Yeah - that sounds pretty tricky if you can't do anything to the markup before it is passed on. Bummer.

Comment: @adc - I'm curious, what PDF engine were you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since [content](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-content/#content) isn't [listed](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-page/#page-properties) as a property that apply within the page context, I don't think you will ever be able achieve it. But remember that it's a work in progress: they might add it on your input.

In spite of that *one day* you will be able to do that instead:

```
@media print {
 @page :nth(n+2) {
  @top-center {
   content: "something";
  }
 }
}
```